# React Native Inverted Flatlist does not render absolute elements correctly

Tags: javascript, react-native

Inverted `Flatlist` that contains absolute positioned elements doesn't seem to allow the absolute positioned elements to overlay previous components / items. Instead, they're forced underneath the previous component. I would like for the absolute positioned elements to render on top of the previous components.

Reproducible code samples:

List Container:

```js
const MessageList = () => {
  const messages = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
  const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <Message isLast={index === 0} />
    )
  }

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={messages}
      inverted
      style={{ flex: 1, paddingHorizontal: 16, paddingBottom: 16 }}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={{ marginVertical: 6 }} />}
    />
  )
}

export default MessageList
```

Message:

```js
const Message = ({ ... }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={{ backgroundColor: 'green', padding: 20 }}>Message here</Text>
      {
        isLast
          ? (
              <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'orange', position: 'absolute', bottom: 40, left: 0, right: 0, top: -20, zIndex: 20 }}>
                <Text>Absolute Positioned</Text>
              </View>

            )
          : null
      }
    </View>
  )
}
```

Result attached as image:
[Incorrectly overlayed element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ydntf.png)

Comment: Have you tried changing the `z-index` css property of the absolutely positioned element?

Comment: @RichardHenage Yes. In the example, the `<View />` contains a zIndex of 20. This doesn't change anything unfortunately.

Comment: I see. Looking more closely, you'll have to change the z-index of the containing `<View>`, not the child `<View>`

Comment: @RichardHenage I responded to your answer. That solution doesn't work. For all intents and purposes, zIndex seems to be ignored. However, that approach does work if the list isn't inverted.

Comment: When the list isn't inverted, does it work even without the extra `zIndex` style?

Comment: I edited my answer. You probably also need the containing `<View>` to have `position: relative` to get the zIndex to work.

Comment: @RichardHenage If the list isn't inverted then yes. It works without the extra `zIndex`, but I need the list to be inverted so unfortunately I can't change that. :(

Comment: Got it. Have you tried with the `position: relative` and the `zIndex: 20` on the containing `<View>`?

Comment: @RichardHenage We should move this discussion to your answer. I have responded there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by making use of the `CellRendererComponent` prop. I was left with the following:

```
const MessageList = () => {
  const messages = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
  const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <Message isLast={index === 0} />
    )
  }

  const renderCell = (props, index) => {
    return (
      <View style={[props.style, { zIndex: messages.length - props.index }]}>
        {props.children}
      </View>
    )
  }

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={messages}
      inverted
      style={{ flex: 1, paddingHorizontal: 16, paddingBottom: 16 }}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={{ marginVertical: 6 }} />}
      CellRendererComponent={renderCell}
    />
  )
}
```

which resulted in the following image:
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNVeJ.png)

Comment: Where do the props for renderCell come from? If I want props.style in renderCell to be something specific, how is it done?

Answer (score 0):

**Old Answer:**

You have to change the `z-index` of the containing `<View>` element, not the child one. You also need to set the containing element to have **`position: relative`** so that `z-index` will work.

**New Answer:**

Okay, I made a code sandbox at https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-lederberg-4wlw8p?file=/src/App.js and figured out that the FlatList is creating a wrapper around each individual list item, so you need to affect the style of those wrappers. This is the code I changed:

```
  return (
    <div className={"my-container"} style={{ overflow: "scroll" }}>
      <FlatList
        data={messages}
        inverted
        style={{ flex: 1, paddingHorizontal: 16, paddingBottom: 16 }}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={{ marginVertical: 6 }} />}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

and you'll need this css

```
  .my-container > * > * > *:first-child {
    z-index: 20;
  }
```

Final result: [image: Absolute positioned FlatList item]

Comment: This is something I also tried implementing. This doesn't fix the issue and still results in the same thing.

Comment: Leaving this comment on this post - https://reactnative.dev/docs/layout-props#:~:text=position%20%E2%80%8B,child%20to%20have%20absolute%20position. position is relative by default, setting position to relative does nothing as it is automatically assumed to be relative.

Comment: I edited my answer after playing around in a codesandbox

Comment: I think you're using React. I'm using React Native and do not have access to classnames. React Native also uses a different rendering system from React.

Comment: Then I don't know how, but you need to somehow get the `z-index: 20` to work on the first direct child of the `<FlatList>`, the child that contains both an `ItemSeperatorComponent` and a `View`.